# Representing a fractional function

Tags: functions

How can I graph this function :

$$f(x)=\dfrac{3x-5}{x-2}$$

I couldn't find any high common factor so that I can cancel $x-2$ and get the function on a form from the main forms. Please tell me what can I do in that kind of problems when I don't find any high common factors and I can't make the function on one of the main forms ?

Comment: $3x - 5$ is not divisible by $x - 2$.  So, it does not get much simpler.  What are you hoping for?

Comment: For what it is worth, with how you have written this it is unclear whether you intend $(3x) - (5/x) - 2$ or if you intend $(3x-5)/(x-2)$.  At least use parentheses if you aren't going to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) like you should.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do mean $\dfrac{3x-5}{x-2}$... as for an alternative on how to represent this, you can "add zero" to the numerator in the form of both adding and subtracting $1$, and splitting the fraction into two.  (*for $x\neq 2$*) We have $\dfrac{3x-5}{x-2}=\dfrac{3x-5-1+1}{x-2}=\dfrac{3x-6}{x-2}+\dfrac{1}{x-2}=3+\dfrac{1}{x-2}$.  Now... this is very similar to the graph of $\dfrac{1}{x}$, just shifted vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

Your function is a [homographic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography#Homographic_function),
$$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
(where $a=3,$ $b=-5,$ $c=1,$ $d=-2$), hence its graph is an hyperbola with a vertical asymptote and an horizontal one.

Look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853027) for its characteristics in the general case.